# I want to set a default reason and status

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to set a default status when I restart my bot my activity status is resetting, I have to use my '-game' command again to set a status. My status change command:

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def game(ctx,*, game):
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="{}".format(game)))
    await ctx.send("Status set to: **{}**".format(game))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that inside the `on_ready` event. Here is a example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='Default Activity'))
```

Then you can change it with your `game` command whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I highly **do not suggest** using change_presence in on_ready within your Bot.

Discord has a high chance to completely disconnect you during the READY or GUILD_CREATE events (1006 close code) and there is nothing you can do to prevent it.

Instead set the activity and status kwargs in the constructor of these Classes. [Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.activity)